# ¿Cuál es el uso correcto de $_SESSION?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php5

estoy guardando en la matriz el usuID, en un archivo php

```
$query = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT COD_USUARIO, TIPO_USUARIO FROM usuarios where USU_USUARIO = '$usuario' and  PASS_USUARIO = '$contrasenia'";)
$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
session_start();
$_SESSION['usuID'] = $filas['COD_USUARIO'];
```

en otro trato de leerlo ya que lo necesito para poder realizar un INSERT INTO, y lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
session_start();
$usuID = $_SESSION[usuID];
$query3 = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO solicitudes (FECHA_SOLICITUD, ESTADO_SOLICITUD, COD_CLIENTE, COD_SERVICIO, COD_USUARIO)  VALUES ('$fecha', '$estado', '$cliente', '$servicio', '$usuID')");
```

no entiendo en que parte estoy fallando ya que el navegador me manda un error fatal que dice que la constante "usuID" no ha sido definida aún y según lo que he consultado en esta página web: https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/php/lecciones/php-sesiones.html si estoy correcto, talvez me pueden enseñar a resolver esta parte, gracias.

Comment: Va entre comillas `$_SESSION['usuID']`

Comment: como te dicen va entre comillas, y luego además estas asignandole el valor mal ya que declaras $fila no $filas-> $_SESSION['usuID'] = $filas['COD_USUARIO'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La variable global `$_SESSION` de *PHP* es un **Array asociativo** y estas accediendo mal a ella, tu estas usando `$_SESSION[usuID]` por lo cual tienes un error de sintaxis, debes acceder a ella así `$_SESSION['usuID']` con comillas

```php
session_start();
$usuID = $_SESSION['usuID'];
```

Te ajunto [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php) más información sobre los arrays asociativos, saludos :)